# poetry dependencies python3.4 with httpx

Tags: python-3.x, python-poetry, httpx

I'm to use pyproject.toml  with poetry (1.1.5, latest).

I want my package supports python>=3.4, and, if it's python>=3.6 then depends on `httpx`, too.

Thus, the pyproject.toml is:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.X"
httpx = {version = "^0.17.1", extras = ["http2"], python = "^3.6"}
```

When I assign the `3.X` to either `3.5`, `3.6`, `3.7`, `poetry lock` works (the python within the venv is 3.8).

However, when it's `3.4`, `poetry lock` reports `SolverProblemError`:

```
  The current project's Python requirement (>=3.4,<4.0) is not compatible with some of the required packages Python requirement:
    - httpcore requires Python >=3.6, so it will not be satisfied for Python >=3.4,<3.6
    - httpcore requires Python >=3.6, so it will not be satisfied for Python >=3.4,<3.6
    - sniffio requires Python >=3.5, so it will not be satisfied for Python >=3.4,<3.5
    - sniffio requires Python >=3.5, so it will not be satisfied for Python >=3.4,<3.5
    - sniffio requires Python >=3.5, so it will not be satisfied for Python >=3.4,<3.5
  
      Because no versions of httpcore match >0.12.1,<0.12.2 || >0.12.2,<0.12.3 || >0.12.3,<0.13
   and httpcore (0.12.1) requires Python >=3.6, httpcore is forbidden.
      And because httpcore (0.12.2) requires Python >=3.6, httpcore is forbidden.
      Because no versions of httpx match >0.17.1,<0.18.0
   and httpx (0.17.1) depends on httpcore (>=0.12.1,<0.13), httpx (>=0.17.1,<0.18.0) requires httpcore (>=0.12.1,<0.13).
      Thus, httpx (>=0.17.1,<0.18.0) requires httpcore (0.12.3).
  (1) So, because httpcore (0.12.3) depends on sniffio (>=1.0.0,<2.0.0), httpx (>=0.17.1,<0.18.0) requires sniffio (>=1.0.0,<2.0.0).
  
      Because no versions of sniffio match >1.0.0,<1.1.0 || >1.1.0,<1.2.0 || >1.2.0,<2.0.0
   and sniffio (1.0.0) requires Python >=3.5, sniffio is forbidden.
      And because sniffio (1.1.0) requires Python >=3.5
   and sniffio (1.2.0) requires Python >=3.5, sniffio is forbidden.
      And because httpx (>=0.17.1,<0.18.0) requires sniffio (>=1.0.0,<2.0.0) (1), httpx is forbidden
      So, because newp depends on httpx (^0.17.1), version solving failed.

 • Check your dependencies Python requirement: The Python requirement can be specified via the `python` or `markers` properties
    
    For httpcore, a possible solution would be to set the `python` property to ">=3.6,<4.0"
    For httpcore, a possible solution would be to set the `python` property to ">=3.6,<4.0"
    For sniffio, a possible solution would be to set the `python` property to ">=3.5,<4.0"
    For sniffio, a possible solution would be to set the `python` property to ">=3.5,<4.0"
    For sniffio, a possible solution would be to set the `python` property to ">=3.5,<4.0"
```

How could I make it work for `python="^3.4"`?

Comment: That looks strange. Can you please open an issue in poetry's [issue tracker](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues)?

Comment: OK. Here it is. https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/3878